# How do I fix the error ' "VC" machine not recognized' for perl Configure

Tags: windows, perl, command-line, makefile, mingw

I am trying to install OpenSSL, but I am running into an error with perl Configure. I type:

```
perl Configure VC-WIN64A
```

and it does some work, but in the end I get an error saying:

```
checking build system type... Invalid configuration `VC-WIN64A': 
machine `VC' not recognized
Configure: error: /bin/sh config/config.sub VC-WIN64A failed
```

I tried tried make check and I received these errors, but I don't understand what they mean:

```
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [Makefile:652: loadavg.exe] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/Program Files/Make/make-4.2'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1088: check-am] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Program Files/Make/make-4.2'
make: *** [Makefile:798: check-recursive] Error 1
```

I couldn't find those files in my file directory does that mean I installed Make incorrectly? Thank you for helping.

EDIT: This is not a duplicate question like the one linked... That question has nothing to do with my problem so I don't know why it was linked. I still can't get perl to recognize my machine.

Comment: You say "*I still can't get perl to recognize my machine.*" ... That is incorrect. You are telling the `Configure` script that you want to use Microsoft's Visual C compiler and tools, but you seem to be using a MinGW (`make`/`gcc`) toolchain. Don't lie to `Configure`. If you want to compile OpenSSL using Visual Studio, do so. The duplicate shows how to do that. You can also read the version specific instructions that came with the OpenSSL release you are trying to build. Either way, your problem does not have anything to do with Perl.

Comment: To put Sinan's comment another way, the top-rated answer to the linked questions says to run the Configure script from the "Visual Studio 2008 x64 Cross Tools Command Prompt", you don't seem to be doing that, and that seems to be why it isn't working for you.  This question is more specific than the other one, so if the answers to the other question don't resolve your problem it isn't a duplicate.  But at this point it seems that they do.  If you still disagree, you need to post considerably more detail about the procedure you are following, including links to specific downloads.